# How can I differentiate between two systems at startup menu

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu

I have two internal Hard disks 500GB each. I want to install KUBUNTU in one and UBUNTU on the other. During startup when I get the OS selection menu. I want to be able to see one os as KUBUNTU and other as UBUNTU. Whereby both the systems are displayed as ubuntu14.04

Thanx in advance

Comment: You see 2x Ubuntu in the grub list? That seems weird: kubuntu is a defined variable in grub and should be displayed. "I want to be able to see one os as KUBUNTU and other as UBUNTU" that is the normal way for grub to show the OS's. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing grub-customizer (installation guide below) to your (K)Ubuntu system that contains GRUB. This GUI tool will provide you a nice set of options with that you can configure your GRUB settings, including names and order of the boot options, default system, screen resolution, fonts, background etc...

How to install grub-customizer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

(source: [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer))

---

Or do you want/need a solution without installing any tools (only terminal/editor usage)?

Comment: Yeah I would have preferred without installing any tools.

Comment: Can you please post the version of your GRUB? To find out the major version, please run `dpkg --list | grep grub`. You will get the output `GRand Unified Bootloader` which means GRUB Legacy (= version 1), or `GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2` which obviously stands for GRUB 2. After that, I will research the actual set of edits that is needed. Please also post the partition names of Ubuntu and KUbuntu (for example Ubuntu: /dev/sda1; KUbuntu /dev/sda3)